# Integration of a determinant

Tags: integration, derivatives, determinant

I know that $$\frac{d\bigg(\det|C_1(x)\;\;C_2(x)\;\;C_3(x)|\bigg)}{dx}$$

$$=\bigg(\det|C_1'(x)\;\;C_2(x)\;\;C_3(x)|\bigg)+\bigg(\det|C_1(x)\;\;C_2'(x)\;\;C_3(x)|\bigg)+\bigg(\det|C_1(x)\;\;C_2(x)\;\;C_3'(x)|\bigg)$$

Is there also a formula for the integration of a determinant?

$$\int{\bigg(\det|C_1(x)\;\;C_2(x)\;\;C_3(x)|\bigg)}dx$$

Comment: If you know $\int f(x){\rm d}x$, $\int g(x){\rm d}x$ and $\int z(x){\rm d}x$ then this tells you very little about what $\int f(x)g(x)z(x){\rm d}x$ is so the answer should be "no" here.

Comment: An example of @Winther's comment: take $f(x)=e^x$, $g(x)=\frac1x$ and $z(x)=1$.